# Adding application to startup of Vista or Win7

Tags: vb.net

How can I add application to startup of VISTA or Win7, using Setup and Deployment package?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Setup project, click View + Editor + File System.  Right-click the left panel, Add special folder, select "User's Startup Folder".  Select it.  Right-click the right panel, Create New Shortcut and select the application.