# C# autostart automatically add application to startup folder

Tags: c#, autostart

Is it possible that C# autostart automatically add application to startup folder. Now i can download and install C# application with autostart but application is not srated automatically when i restart windows. How to do that?

Comment: What makes you think your users _want_ your program in Startup?

Comment: it is not open application for all users it is internal and they need this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding application to startup of Vista or Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831568/adding-application-to-startup-of-vista-or-win7)

Comment: no it is not duplicated. We have just win XP.

Comment: My condolences, and that solution should work on XP as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it :

```
RegistryKey rkey = 
    Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
rkey.SetValue("YourApplicationName", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start some applications< I suggest you to go for [Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074%28VS.71%29.aspx) :)

Comment: with one click deployment i can install application but by default it is not started automatically when windows restart. I need that will start automatically when windows restart. What to add in C# code for that?

Comment: as I said, your applications cant start with windows if its not Windows Services. Windows Service Technology exists for this requirement. if you check your system's Local Services, you can see what I mean. You can start automatically applications, or you can attach schedule to start etc.

Comment: You *can* make an app start at windows boot without making a windows service. Making a windows service is probably one of the worst ways to solve this problem. Take a look at Hans' comment on the question.

Comment: When you create a windows service, you must add project installer. and using command prompt, put installutil.exe to your project exe root, and type "installutil.exe -i YourApp.exe" to command prompt. This will install your Windows Service App to your system. You can start/stop configure your service at Local Services

Comment: @Serkan Windows services are meant for something which kind of needs to run as a background process without any user interface. I have not come across a servie so far which can interact with the users desktop. May be to resolve the problem we can add a custome action to the setup or deployment project or whatever tool is used to create the installer for this application. This custom action will copy the shortcut for the exe to the startup folder. You can make use of package and deployment software like Windows Installer Script (WIX) or Installshield to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Active Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Setup), no programming, just a few registry entries to create in HKLM

> Active Setup is the installation technology Microsoft used for downloading and installing Internet Explorer versions 4 to 6. It was designed to selectively download and install signed Internet Explorer components via the Internet. This significantly reduced the amount of data to download as also the time required for updates. Active Setup could also resume partially completed downloads from the point where they were interrupted.